# monotouch build error when deploying: compressing the resources failed

Tags: c#, iphone, xamarin.ios

I'm using Monotouch and it works fine with the simulator, but when I try to deploy to the phone or to an iPad, I get a build error:

```
Compressing the resources failed: Unable to rename .../../../../circle-pngcrush.png to .../../../../circle.png
```

I'm at a complete loss and can't find anything online about this error.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Check the casing - ie, that the file names in your project are cased the same way they are in the file system.  The OSX file system is case aware, while the iOS file system is case sensitive.  So bad casing might be OK on the simulator but fail on the actual device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have permission to rename the file in that location. first check with right click on folder and Get Info and look at the permission. Sometimes you can only read, but can not write!

- 'Get info' on the folder. (CMD I or from the Finder Menu, File > Get Info)
  Click the unlock icon in the lower left-hand corner.
- Authenticate.
- If you can't proceed with the following then you are not a user/ owner with admin rights
- Select your username from the list under "Name". (Sharing and Permissions).

From the gear drop-down menu at the bottom of the Get Info window select "Make yourusername (Me) the owner" .